# R textConnection slow speed

Tags: r, hadoop

I have multiple files to load and want to concatenate them together into 1 data frame.  I am trying to use textConnection, but it is running very slowly.  Here is what my data looks like when I load it into R:

```
"1995200008,10,1995,5190.61,73300"   
"1995200010,1,1995,6776.44,42652"   
"1995200011,11,1995,2315.83,4169"    
"1995200014,6,1995,9846.79,2113"    
"1995200017,8,1995,3978.93,2449"     
"1995200018,6,1995,3582.69,2449"    
"1995200022,7,1995,10409.18,2859"
```

I can not use read.csv because it is using a library to pull data from Hadoop.  The double quotes are in the data.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
tmp <- hdfs.read.text.file(filename)
tmp1 <- read.table(textConnection(tmp), sep = ",")
```

Does anyone know of a way that will run faster?

Comment: Have you tried `readLines` or `scan`?

Comment: For what I'm doing those ideas will not work.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Would it also be slow if the data came from a normal file?
If so, the speed problem could simply come from the size of the file:
specifying the column types (`colClasses`) usually improves things.

Comment: Have you tried joining the files before the read.table()?

Comment: I had the same problem with a 9 MB dataset, textConnection is really slow. Instead, I write it to a file and use read.csv(file) and that's much faster

Comment: Use a system call to collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

The `hdfs.read.text.file` returns a character vector.

You may directly pass the array to read.table function without creating the `textConnection`. Try the following code,

```
charV <- hdfs.read.text.file(filename)
df <- read.table(text = charV, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```